# scala chained conditional mapping - `ifDefined` method

Tags: scala, if-statement, option-type

Is there a more concise way of conditionally mapping over a value like in:

```scala
val userName: Option[String] = Some("Bob")
val address: Option[String] = Some("Planet Earth")

val dbQuery = new Query()

val afterUserName = 
  userName.map(u => dbQuery.copy(userName = u))
    .getOrElse(dbQuery)

val modifiedQuery = 
  address.map(a => afterUserName.copy(address = a))
    .getOrElse(afterUserName)
```

I wish there was an `ifDefined` method available on all types like in the following block. This removes the `.getOrElse(...)` call.

```scala
dbQuery
  .ifDefined(userName)((d, u) => d.copy(userName = u)
  .ifDefined(address)((d, a) => d.copy(address = a)
```

Comment: Is this working code? That `copy` syntax looks a bit odd.

Comment: This is scala code. `copy` is a method of case classes. I'll edit the question and make it clear that it is scala code.

Comment: Ah, you were right. I changed `d.copy(d.userName = u)` into `d.copy(_.userName = u)`.

Comment: I know it is Scala, but you are passing a function to `copy` which seems rather odd. Typically it would be `copy(userName = u)` where `userName` is the name of a field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following might be shorter

```
dbQuery.copy(
  userName  = userName.getOrElse(dbQuery.userName),
  address = address.getOrElse(dbQuery.address)
)
```